# How do I open back the properties panel?

Tags: interface, windows

[image: There should be the scene collection]

There should be a list of all the items and their properties here.
I don't know if there's a way to bring it back

I don't need the  <kbd>N</kbd> panel, I need this one:

[image]

Comment: Press N! Read the manual!

Comment: Dude, I don't need the N panel. I need the big panel with all the items etc.

Comment: https://youtu.be/8XyIYRW_2xk?t=61

Comment: Ah! That's the outliner and properties panel. Looks as if you've gone full screen with the 3D view so Ctrl-Space should toggle back to the normal layout.

Comment: @JohnEason I've been experimenting and closed it by right click > area > close area

Comment: Ah well... If you've been playing... This is a quick YT tutorial on problems with workspaces in Blender: https://youtu.be/h9xt_UvsSuo.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and may be [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing). Please use the [edit] button below the post to change you text into regular case.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to do it:
**(Try pressing Ctrl+Space before repeating that since you could have accidentaly gone fullscreen)**

1. Point your cursor to the right bottom of the blender window untill you see a crosshair
   [image]
2. Hold left mouse button and pull left, you'll see a new 3D Viewport, in this viewport click this icon

[image]

3. Select "Outliner"
   [image]
4. You can now repeat the process to open "Properties" panel, but now, instead of "Outliner", you should choose, well, "Properties"
   [image]

Comment: [Have a look at the documentation.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/index.html#) It will be useful when you need to talk about parts of Blender's UI.

Comment: Docs are good but sometimes you can't find the answer there since there are a lot of text and sections

Comment: Everything there is quite useful, so no harm to read it. In this case I mean just for communication. It is Outliner and Properties editor, not "properties panel", [panels](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/tabs_panels.html#panels) are sort of regions in it.

Comment: But it seems even official tutorials get it wrong... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8XyIYRW_2xk&t=61s this one linked before in the comments for example. He is talking about areas when he says 'panels'. That is not very helpful...